# Pass speech recognition state via useContext

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I click on the button recognition starts listening. I want to change the button's color while the recognition is listening, to make it more convenient for users.

For that I'm trying to pass `true/false` in useContext when recognition starts and stops, but when I click on the button I'm getting `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import AppContext from './AppContext'

function runSpeechRecognition() {
  const { setListening } = useContext(AppContext)

  // new speech recognition object
  var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition()

  // This runs when the speech recognition service starts
  recognition.onstart = function () {
    console.log('We are listening. Try speaking into the microphone.')
  }

  recognition.onspeechend = function () {
    // when user is done speaking
    recognition.stop()
    setListening(false)
  }

  // start recognition
  recognition.start()
  setListening(true)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        var transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript
        resolve(transcript)
      }
}

export default runSpeechRecognition
```

Full Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute a hook in an event handler and you `runSpeechRecognition` is actually a misnamed [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). It became one as soon as you used another hook inside the function.

Embrace custom hooks, and have it return a function that does the logic:

```
import { useContext, useCallback } from 'react'
import AppContext from './AppContext'

function useSpeechRecognition() {
  const { setListening } = useContext(AppContext)

  return useCallback(() => {
   // new speech recognition object
    var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition()

    // This runs when the speech recognition service starts
    recognition.onstart = function () {
      console.log('We are listening. Try speaking into the microphone.')
    }

    recognition.onspeechend = function () {
      // when user is done speaking
      recognition.stop()
      setListening(false)
    }

    // start recognition
    recognition.start()
    setListening(true)
  }, [setListening ])

 
}

export default useSpeechRecognition
```

And then use it like so in your component

```
const Example = () => {
    const start = useSpeechRecognition()

    const yourClickHandler = () => {
        start()
    }

}
```